# Get the correct DAY_OF_WEEK String

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am facing problem that I am always getting day `sun` in my query although today is `monday` also for my query `mon-fri`. In my code WDay has the value `2` therefor I have built the switch case structure like this so I should get for today  the value `mon-fri` and not `sun`?

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int WDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); //Here day has the value 2.

    // Create a statement
    Statement stt = con.createStatement();

    DatabaseMetaData dbm = con.getMetaData();

    ResultSet stopsExist = dbm.getTables(null, null, "stops", null);

    if (stopsExist.next()) {
        // the stops and arrrivaltimes tables exist.

        PreparedStatement preparedLatLong = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT lat, longi, name from stops");
        ResultSet rsLatLong = preparedLatLong.executeQuery();
        while (rsLatLong.next()) {
            double lat_stop = rsLatLong.getDouble("lat");
            double lon_stop = rsLatLong.getDouble("longi");
            double distStops = haversineDistance(latD, longD, lat_stop,
                    lon_stop);
            if (distStops <= 10) {
                String stop_name = rsLatLong.getString("name");

                String day = "";
                switch (WDay) {
                case 2:
                    day = "mon-fri";
                case 3:
                    day = "mon-fri";
                case 4:
                    day = "mon-fri";
                case 5:
                    day = "mon-fri";
                case 6:
                    day = "mon-fri";
                case 7:
                    day = "sat";
                case 1:
                    day = "sun";

                }
                 //In the query here, day has the string sun instead of mon-fri
                PreparedStatement preparedTime = con
                        .prepareStatement("SELECT route from arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops"
                                + " ON arrivaltimes.stop_id=stops.stop_id "
                                + "WHERE weekday = '" + day + "'"
                                + " and time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i') and name LIKE '" + stop_name + "'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `break` statements in each block:

```
switch (WDay) {
        case 2 :
            day = "mon-fri";
            break;
        case 3 :
            day = "mon-fri";
            break;
        case 4 :
            day = "mon-fri";
            break;
        case 5 :
            day = "mon-fri";
            break;
        case 6 :
            day = "mon-fri";
            break;
        case 7 :
            day = "sat";
            break;
        case 1 :
            day = "sun";
            break;
        default :
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal day: " + WDay);

    }
```

I also like to **always** add a default case, in this case it would be more out of principle but sometimes this helps you in some weird cases you never thought of.

If aware, you could do it without breaks, using Java's **fall-through** mechanics. Depends on what you consider more readable. At least this makes changes easier as you have to only edit one line instead of five (or even more lines).

```
switch (WDay) {
        case 1 :
            day = "sun";
            break;
        case 2 : // fall-through
        case 3 : // fall-through
        case 4 : // fall-through
        case 5 : // fall-through
        case 6 :
            day = "mon-fri";
            break;
        case 7 :
            day = "sat";
            break;
        default :
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal day: " + WDay);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `switch` statement. If you do not add `break;` after each case, your code will simply continue to the next case.

this should fix it:

```
            switch (WDay) {
            case 2:
                day = "mon-fri";
                break;
            case 3:
                day = "mon-fri";
                break;
            case 4:
                day = "mon-fri";
                break;
            case 5:
                day = "mon-fri";
                break;
            case 6:
                day = "mon-fri";
                break;
            case 7:
                day = "sat";
                break;
            case 1:
                day = "sun";
                break;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `break;` after each case

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in
>   switch blocks **fall through**: All statements after the matching case
>   label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of
>   subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered

Answer (score 1):

The first five CASEs can be simplified:

```
switch (WDay) {
        case 7 :
            day = "sat";
            break;
        case 1 :
            day = "sun";
            break;
        default :
            day = "mon-fri";
    }
```